# Some questions on Simple-Schema for Meteor

Tags: meteor

For those who use Simple Schema for Meteor validation I've got some questions (after having used it for a while):

**1.**
Does SimpleSchema support square bracket notation? All the examples show it using dot notation. I did the following square bracket implementation:

```
Schemas.NamesCollection = new SimpleSchema({
  name: {
    type: Object
  },
  "name[first_name]" : {
    type: String,
    optional: false,
    label: "First Name"
  },
  "name[last_name]" : {
    type: String,
    optional: false,
    label: "Last Name"
  }
});


{{> afQuickField name="name[first_name]"}}
{{> afQuickField name="name[last_name]"}}
```

I noticed that the form validation worked just fine as I'm filling out the form, but the final insertion of the data into the collection fails with a validation error (the same exact error that had passed earlier on the form validation but is now failing on insertion).

There are a lot of reasons to use square bracket notation, obviously. Dot notation has tons of limitations, despite being more readable.

**2.** Looking at the example above defining the schema, the keys in the schema have to be the full path in the object. You have to declare `name[first_name]` to assign a schema to it, which means that you're not only defining the properties of `first_name`, but you're also defining the **structure** of the object. `first_name` **has** to be nested inside `name`.

You can't, for example, just do

```
Schemas.NamesCollection = new SimpleSchema({
  name: {
    type: Object
  },
  first_name : {
    type: String,
    optional: false,
    label: "First Name"
  },
  last_name : {
    type: String,
    optional: false,
    label: "Last Name"
  }
});
```

And then proceed to store `first_name` and `last_name` inside of `name`, can you?

Comment: What are the limitations of dot notation?

Comment: How do you put in a variable name in dot notation? How do you put in "something with spaces" in dot notation?

Comment: @Akshat, so you're using square bracket notation, not dot notation. If you could only use dot notation, since Simple Schema does not seem to support bracket notation, you'd be in trouble, right? You simply couldn't do `x.something with spaces` unless you used square bracket notation.

Comment: I spoke to the creator of SimpleSchema. The issue is that Mongo only supports dot notation for all queries, so that's what SimpleSchema uses. It would be extra code to convert any bracket notation into dot notation. SO the takeaway is that since SimpleSchema depends on dot notation, any form input fields need to have their `name=` be in dot notation **beforehand**. If you need to use square bracket notation for anything, you need to eventually convert it into something that dot notation supports for you're creating your field names.